# Broken view of src folder for package explorer with modelling nature in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-sirius, sirius

In Eclipse 2022-12, I have installed Sirius v7.0.7.202301170754 and downloaded the Sirius example from https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/DomainModelTutorial.

The visualization of the src-gen folder in both Model Explorer and Project Explorer is broken:

[image]

In the package explorer it's working fine:

[image]

Interesting thing: if I remove the Modelling nature from the project everything shows up correctly!

[image]

Do you now how to fix this? Of course the Modelling nature is needed!!

Thank you!

Comment: Does creating a new project work? Does the `.project` files example vs. new project differ?

Comment: Creating a new project has the same effect... And the `.project` files are exactly the same..

Comment: Maybe [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=581001). Please upgrade to Eclipse 2023-06 and comment on the bug whether this issue still exists in 2023-06.

Comment: Ok, I tried with 2023-06 and still the same bug. I've installed only ECore tools v3.4.0, but they say the support is only up to 2021-06 (in the bug report).